# Not able to call TablayoutActivity from AppcombatActivity

Tags: android

I want to call my tablayout activity , when user clicked on Item Menu from Action View Item ,

But I am getting error :

06-15 14:17:01.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1365): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Linfo/muscle/reboot/activity/Wrk_plan_gain;

Here is my Main activity from where I am calling Tab layout Activity .

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    public MainActivity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    String diet_saved;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        pref = this.getPreferences(1);
        diet_saved=pref.getString("diettype", "main");

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
         if (id == R.id.workout_menu) {

             startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Wrk_plan_gain.class));
                finish();

            return true;
        }

        /*if(id == R.id.action_search){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
         */
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {


        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new KnowYourBodyFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new YourResultFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new YourMacroResultFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_macro);
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new DietPlanFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_Diet);
            break;

        case 5:
            title = getString(R.string.title_Exit);
            finish();
            break;

        default:
        }


        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }
}
```

and I am trying call this Activity

```
public class Wrk_plan_gain extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {


     public Wrk_plan_gain() {
         // Required empty public constructor
     }
     //This is our tablayout
     private TabLayout tabLayout;

     //This is our viewPager
     private ViewPager viewPager;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.wrk_plan_layout_gain);

         //Adding toolbar to the activity
         Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

         //Initializing the tablayout
         tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

         //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
         tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
         tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
         tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab3"));
         tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

         //Initializing viewPager
         viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

         //Creating our pager adapter
         Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

         //Adding adapter to pager
         viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

         //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views
         tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
         viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
     }

     @Override
     public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

     }
 }
```

Also it will every much help full I f I can call this activity from Nav drawer Item ..

I am not able to get it work , in both cases .

Comment: `AppcombatActivity`. I want to use the Combat Activity too :P

Comment: @Sujit Soni Is tablayout activity added to your manifest ?

Comment: Yes It is , I also tried to set tablayout activity has a launcher activity , so I am getting class not found error..